# Telegram bot inline keyboard disappeared after first click

Tags: laravel, telegram, telegram-bot, botman

I'm developing a telegram bot via [Botman](https://botman.io) which displays telegram inline keyboard with callback mode. After receiving `callback_query` from telegram, I will respond with `answerCallbackQuery` which works just fine for the first time.

The problem is that after first click on the callback button, the button will disappear from the message.

The button remains appeared until the telegram's `callback_query` request execution finished on the bot server. After putting `sleep(10)` on bot's server, the button disappeared after 10 seconds.

The Botman Handler code:

```php
$botman->hears('/inline', function (BotMan $bot) {
    $bot->reply(
        "Inline Keyboard Message",
        Keyboard::create()
            ->type(Keyboard::TYPE_INLINE)
            ->addRow(KeyboardButton::create("callback")->callbackData("callback"))
            ->oneTimeKeyboard(false)
            ->toArray()
    );
});


$botman->hears('callback', function (Botman $bot) {
    $callback = Request::input('callback_query.id');

    $bot->sendRequest('answerCallbackQuery', [
        'callback_query_id' => $callback,
        'text' => 'Message Received',
        'show_alert' => true,
    ]);
    
    sleep(10);
});
```

I even tried to update keyboards after sending `answerCallbackQuery` via `editMessageReplyMarkup` method. Even though the buttons get updated but they still disappeared after request execution finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by setting `hideInlineKeyboard` config under `telegram` configuration entry. This configuration was not documented or existed on example telegram configuration file in `botman` package, So I wasn't aware of it.

Final botman configuration file:

```php
return [
    'telegram' => [
        'token' => env('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'),

        'hideInlineKeyboard' => false,
    ],
];
```